# Android: Shifting elements within array and to another array within a loop

Tags: java, android, arrays, loops

I have two different arrays, one with 3 slots (arrayOne) and another with 2 (arrayTwo). I am entering values into the one with 3 slots and then once the array has 3 values, the value first entered into the array (at arrayOne[0]) will move to arrayTwo. The values in arrayOne are then shifted (arrayOne[0] = arrayOne[1])

Is there a way for me to rearrange the values within the arrays with a loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you can move elements around an array using [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)), no loop necessary.

In your case, to move the first element from arrayOne to arrayTwo and then the last two elements in arrayOne to the first two slots, you can do:

```
arrayTwo[0] = arrayOne[0]; //Move first element from arrayOne to arrayTwo
System.arraycopy(arrayOne, 1, arrayOne, 0, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @KevinLi No problem :) If this solved your problem, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the green tick next to it.